# What is Blend? and what is its relation to WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, blend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF Applications: Visual Studio vs. Expression Blend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368640/wpf-applications-visual-studio-vs-expression-blend)

I was starting to learn WPF then i saw on youtube that someone used microsoft expression Blend to make some UI and integrate it into visual studio
My question is

why is blend used for and what we design in it could be designed in wpf visual studio?

Why would microsoft would release it separately for UI?

is there any relation between WPF and silverlight?

sorry if it is a stupid question i am a bit confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression Blend is part of Microsoft’s Expression Studio suite of design tools. It is the production tool for designing and building user interfaces for Silverlight on the Web  for WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) on Windows.

just have a look at this link

http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd279539.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To add to Kishore Silverlight and WPF has lot in common you can think Silverlight as trimmed down version of WPF adapted for web oriented UIs. Both WPF and Silverlight use concept of XAML to describe the UI backed by a managed programming model and UI framework