# What is the Use of Blend

Tags: c#, expression-blend

What's  the use of blend software,  when all the work coding and designing can be done in Visual Studio very well and even Intellisence not work in blend for c#

Comment: This is not a question, but if you want to know, Blend is oriented to Designers, not developers. It has greater design features than Visual Studio, such as the ability to create brushes graphically, create paths, combine them, and whatnot. Also has features to facilitate the creation / cloning of ControlTemplates and things like that. Im not a designer myself so I don't use it much.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368640/wpf-applications-visual-studio-vs-expression-blend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft blend is most powerful tool from Microsoft for designing and mainly for template editing for Controls

And yes intellisence not work in blend, but u can install resharper 7 of take profit of intellisence in Blend

Answer (score 3):

Blend is optimized for easy and powerful design of the user interface, while Visual Studio is an IDE. You can give Blend to someone, who has no clue about programming, but can easily draw GUIs for your applications.

Answer (score 0):

With visual studios you CAN do everything but blend makes it easy. Are you going to make a ful webpage from notepad or are you going to use Dreamweaver? Blend makes making GUIs and complicated siliverlight animations easy. It also makes creating layouts and storyboards for all these elements FAST. Give it a try.